# Swift - pageviewcontroller tableview in scrollview using snapkit

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, snapkit

I just faced a really difficult point while making a complicated view that has pageViewController, tableview, and scrollview.

This is what I want to program

[image: view structure]
case 1) scroll up : button stactview and pageviewcontroller locate headerview.snp.botttom and hide red view and tableview will scroll

case 2) scroll down : show red view, button stactview and pageviewcontroller locate red view.snp.bottom (like photo)

I made it like these cases,  but the problem is tableview in pageviewcontroller didn't move.
What should I do to make it smooth scrolling?
I found example what I want to make
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tsucres/HeaderedTabScrollView/master/Screenshots/customAnim.gif

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/MXSegmentedPager/3.2.2/

I build view programmatically using snapkit

```
self.tabTopValue = 440 // redview height

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom)
        }
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        }
        redView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.equalTo(contentView.snp.leading)
            make.trailing.equalTo(contentView.snp.trailing)
            make.top.equalTo(header.snp.bottom).offset(0)
            make.height.equalTo(440)
        }
        
        // tabbar
        tabButtonStackView.addArrangedSubview(historyInfoButton)
        tabButtonStackView.addArrangedSubview(graphButton)
        tabButtonStackView.addArrangedSubview(lineageInfoButton)
        contentView.addSubview(tabButtonStackView)
        tabButtonStackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(contentView)
            tabTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(self.tabTopValue).constraint
            make.height.equalTo(40)
        } 
        addChild(pageViewController)
        contentView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        pageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)

        pageViewController.view.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(tabButtonStackView.snp.bottom)
            make.leading.trailing.equalTo(contentView)
            make.height.equalTo(scrollView)
            make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp.bottom).offset(0)
        }
```

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print("detail scroll = \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")

        
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            self.tabButtonStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                self.tabTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(scrollView.contentOffset.y + tabTopValue).constraint
            }
        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0 { 
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, animations: {
                self.tabButtonStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                    self.tabTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(self.headerView.snp.bottom).offset(self.tabTopValue).constraint
                }
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < tabTopValue {
            self.tabButtonStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                self.tabTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(tabTopValue - scrollView.contentOffset.y).constraint
            }

        } else if scrollView.contentOffset.y > tabTopValue {
            self.tabButtonStackView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
                self.tabTopConstraint = make.top.equalTo(headerView.snp.bottom).offset(0).constraint
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to explain a bit more clearly what you're trying to do. Should the `red view` be "covered" or "pushed"? https://imgur.com/a/thqK5Cq ... Do you want to move up the page view controller (with the table view) when dragging the red view up and down? Or only when dragging the buttons and/or table view?

Comment: @DonMag sorry for the poor explanation. The red view will be 'covered' when dragging the red view up and down

Comment: Should the table view only be scrollable when the buttons are all the way at the top? Or, do you want to drag the buttons+pageViewController (which contains the table view) part of the way and then scroll the table view? Do you want to try and drag everything up and down ***while*** dragging the table view? Can you live with the tableView *always* being scrollable, and only moving the rest up and down when dragging on the "button bar"? Be ***really, completely detailed*** in your description of what you want to do, or we'll spend time coming up with something you don't really want.

Comment: @DonMag I found an example https://githubmemory.com/repo/tsucres/HeaderedTabScrollView. I want to do something like this.

Comment: It's good that you found a solution... so you might as well close or delete this question.